# Собранный проект запускается на Windows, но не запускается на UNIX

Tags: java, javafx, maven, jar, сборка

Имеется код, который представляет из себя простейшее окно с использованием JavaFX. Собирается при помощи Maven, полученный jar запускается на Windows, но на Ubuntu не запускается.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ru.quwantoq.sample.Main
```

Снизу прикладываю pom.xml (замена "/" на "." ни к чему не приводит)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.quwantoq</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>ru/quwantoq/sample/Main</mainClass>

                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>ru/quwantoq/sample/Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Класс `Main`

```
package ru.quwantoq.sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
}
```

Класс `Controller`

```
package ru.quwantoq.sample;

public class Controller {
}
```

В `resources`

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane fx:controller="ru.quwantoq.sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Вы класс `ru.quwantoq.sample.Main` не прикладываете к проекту во втором случае. Причём тут maven?

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, даже после добавления.

Comment: Покажите структуру вашего проекта.

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c630717/v630717221/6927/rmDxqeVy5Ig.jpg

Comment: У вас папка называется "ru.quwantoq.sample"?

Comment: Нет, это 3 папки

Comment: Так вопрос решён, или проблема осталась?

Comment: @LEQADA
 
Осталась, так и не решилась

Comment: Покажите, что у вас в classpath.

Comment: @LEQADA кроме java 1.8 ничего

Comment: Покажите класс `Main`

Comment: @LEQADA     
    http://pastebin.com/dUbdtTp4

Comment: Я обновил ваш вопрос. Добавьте все файлы проекта в вопрос. Так гадать можно долго.

Comment: Все файлы добавил в впорос

Comment: А почему вы везде mainClass указываете через слеши, а не через точки?

Comment: @Russtam Не имеет значения

Comment: Там, где вы посмотрели classpath, есть вкладка Sources. Покажите его содержимое.

Comment: @LEQADA

http://puu.sh/m4XRU/9b4f60d106.png

Comment: Вы это всё сейчас через Windows показываете?

Comment: @LEQADA

На Windows и Ubuntu одинаковые проекты. Оба запускаются из IDEA.

Comment: Но вы показываете через Windows. Я вижу виндовый путь. Обновите все данные данными из Ubuntu

Comment: @LEQADA

https://pp.vk.me/c630717/v630717351/6639/Mslxq_HMMfE.jpg

Comment: Измените кириллицу в пути к проекту.

Comment: @LEQADA  Дело не в ней

Comment: Вы случайно настройки виртуальной машины для maven не трогали?

Comment: @LEQADA
Нет не трогал, файл собранный с чистого листа работает на Windows, но отказывается запускаться на Ubuntu

Comment: А если удалить проект  и создать по-новому? С новой директорией.

Comment: @LEQADA Пробовал, не подействовало

Comment: Попробуйте запустить IDEA от имени суперпользователя. Последнее подозрение у меня падает на права.

Comment: @LEQADA
Нет, всё тоже самое. Jar запускается на Windows и не запускается на Ubuntu

Comment: Я попробовал. У меня работает.

Comment: @LEQADA

https://www.dropbox.com/s/55yddundfzhea10/sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?dl=0

Можете запустить этот?

Comment: Да, запускается и работает.

Comment: @LEQADA  На Ubuntu? Можно команду которой Вы запускаете?

Comment: А! Вы неправильно пытаетесь запустить! Нужно так `java -jar  sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: @LEQADA
https://pp.vk.me/c630717/v630717351/6682/9Qf84N-cjWg.jpg

Comment: @LeonidLunin Дайте вывод `java -version`.

Comment: @kff
`openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)`

Скачал отдельно самую новую, через неё тоже не стартует

Comment: Подтверждаю. Не запускается. `openjdk version "1.8.0_72-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-internal-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b05, mixed mode)`. А вот на этом работает: `java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: @kff Очень интересные дела

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По результатам экспериментов выяснилось, что в OpenJDK отсутствует JavaFX. Если собирать и запускать через Oracle JDK, то всё работает, но при попытке запуска собранного jar-ника через OpenJDK возникает указанная ошибка. При сборке с OpenJDK ошибка возникает уже на стадии компиляции:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project sample: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[3,26] package javafx.application does not exist
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[4,19] package javafx.fxml does not exist
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[5,20] package javafx.scene does not exist
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[6,20] package javafx.scene does not exist
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[7,20] package javafx.stage does not exist
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[9,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Application
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[12,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Stage
[ERROR] location: class ru.quwantoq.sample.Main
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[11,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[13,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Parent
[ERROR] location: class ru.quwantoq.sample.Main
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[13,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getClass()
[ERROR] location: class ru.quwantoq.sample.Main
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[13,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable FXMLLoader
[ERROR] location: class ru.quwantoq.sample.Main
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[15,35] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Scene
[ERROR] location: class ru.quwantoq.sample.Main
[ERROR] /media/sf__Shared_Folder/project/src/main/java/ru/quwantoq/sample/Main.java:[21,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method launch(java.lang.String[])
[ERROR] location: class ru.quwantoq.sample.Main
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Компилятор не может найти компоненты JavaFX.

Вероятно, стоит использовать Oracle JDK для работы с JavaFX.

**Дополнение**

Если рассматривать конкретно *Ubuntu 15.10*, то в ней для работы приложений *JavaFX* можно поставить пакет **OpenJFX**:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

После этого всё собирается и работает.

Интересно, что *IntelliJ IDEA* автоматически не "подхватывает" установленный пакет *OpenJFX*. Чтобы она восприняла изменения можно либо добавить jar-пакеты с классами вручную, либо же просто удалить SDK и создать заново. Напомню, что настройки SDK находятся здесь:

*File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs*

P.S. Ещё интересно, что в *Linux Mint 17.2* пакет *OpenJFX* отсутствует.

Comment: Однако при запуске из IDEA и выборе Open JDK в качестве SDK мы имеем рабочее приложение.

Comment: @LeonidLunin На чистой системе с одной OpenJDK IDEA тоже не может собрать проект. Может быть, она как-то зацепила Oracle JDK или его часть?

Comment: А на чистой системе с Oracle JDK она из IDEA командой "Run" запускается?

Comment: @LeonidLunin Нет. Не запускается.

Comment: Теперь я вообще ничего не понимаю